# How to echo a form value into url without page refresh

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, radio-button, return-value

I'd like to echo a radiobutton value into my url so when the value is 'day' and my url seems to be 'analyse1.php'. I want to put the value 'day' between 'analyse' and '1' so the url will be 'analyseday1'

So far, I got my form:

```
<form>
<input name="selectieperiode" value="day" type="radio">
<input name="selectieperiode" value="week" type="radio">
</form>
```

Plus a little bit of javascript to redirect

```
  <script>
  form=document.getElementById("someForm");
  function scansnormaal() {
  form.action="analyse1.php";
  form.submit();
  }
  </script>
```

How can I accomplish to make form.action="analyse1.php" in this case be form.action="analyseday1.php or analyseweek1.php when the radiobuttons which is selected gets the value 'week'.

Maybe something like?

```
  ...
  form.action="analyse'$valueradiobutton'1.php";
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the point since your PHP gets the value of the radio when the form is submitted. But if you insist:

```
function scansnormaal() {
  var form=document.getElementById("someForm"); // assuming id="someForm"
  var periode=""; // default
  if (form.selectieperiode[0].checked) periode=form.selectieperiode[0].value;
  else if (form.selectieperiode[1].checked) periode=form.selectieperiode[1].value;
  form.action="analyse"+periode+"1.php";
  form.submit();
}
```